# Class Inheritance default constructor cannot be referenced

Tags: c++

Questions : 33978185 , 32569833 didn't helped me.

By the way, in question 33978185 this error is considered as a bug, but since im using VS2017 i think it should be fixed by now.

Question 40181845 is using structs and i dont understand it quite well...
Question 38469597 says that i should make class B - friend class, is that the case here too?

I tried to search for more solutions but i havent got what i need.

Consinder my level of programming knowledge of object oriented c++ :  Advanced> Normal > Begginer.
I am Normal.

I have class A, and class B:

```
class A
{
    protected:
  int q;
  int w;
public:
  A(int);
  functionE();
  functionR();
};

class B:public A
{
public:
functionT();
};
```

in `main` when i want to create a object of class `B`, I get error:

> the default constructor "objectname" cannot be referenced -- its a deleted function.

From my knowledge of object oriented programming, when some members are protected, they can be accessed by the inherited class, and if inheritance is public, it can access public function.

I want my class B to have bonus `functionT()` and nothing else, but as i said, be able to access protected members of class.

One solution is to actually code `functionT()` in class `A`, which removes the need for class `B`, but I don't want that.

What should i do?

Comment: Please include the code which generates the error too (it is obvious to us what is going wrong in this case, but often it won't be).  That's why *complete* is there in [mcve].

Comment: See this page for information on when constructors get default declared and deleted: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

Answer (score 5):

When you're trying to create an object of `class B`, you get an error as you didn't declare any constructor. `B` can't have a default constructor, as `A` doesn't have one either (when you declared `A(int)` as `A` constructor, you implicitly deleted the default constructor).

You can either create a default constructor for A, or default it by `A() = default`

or create a constructor for B, like so

```
B() : A(0) {}
B(int i) : A(i) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

By providing the constructor `A(int)` the default constructor `A()` gets deleted. However, when creating an instance of class `B` it must call the constructor of its superclass `A`. The only way you provide is calling the default constructor, which doesn't exist anymore and thus your code does not compile.

In order for it to compile, you need to tell `B` how it is supposed to construct `A`. You can for example add this constructor to `B`: `B(int a) : A(a) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a custom constructor for class `A` it needs to be called by the constructor of class `B`.
The generated 'empty' constructor of class `B` tries to call the 'empty' one of class `A`, which is no longer available. So you need to write a constructor for `B` as well.

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A(0) {}
    /* or  */
    B(int v) : A(v) {}
};
```

Comment: Hmm...Okay, i didnt know that. Thank you.

Comment: @Object Yes.  Either with A(), or by giving the `int` constructor a default value: `A(int = 0);`

Comment: What i did is actualy creating default constructor for A, like A() {};   and than creating default constructor for B, like B() {}; and that worked out for me. I get no errors now. What i didnt know is that when i created custom constructor the default one gets deleted.

Comment: @Object this works as well, of course. Btw, by adding a default constructor for `A` you don't need the one for `B` anymore

Comment: Yes that worked too.I now deleted B constructor.